# How to get all the Open Graph Beta actions generated by an app

Tags: api, facebook-opengraph

I have seen this question multiple times, but could not find any answer (sorry for repeating it):

It is already possible to get all actions for custom app actions and objects:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/me/{appNameSpace}:{action}/{object}
```

This will list all the actions generated by an app, but only for a given user...

How do I get all the actions generated by an app (for all its users)? I've tried this request with an app access token :

```
https://graph.facebook.com/{appId}/{appNameSpace}:{action}/{object}
```

But it does not work...

I was also looking for an activities or actions FQL table, since each action has an id, they should be accessible somewhere.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

For the current user you can, as you note, request all that user's activity in an app, but you can't see 'all activity across all users for this all' - you'd need to store this information on your side at the time of publish and corelate it later.

Many apps need to do this anyway, as they need to update the actions or objects at a later time, or allow the user to select to unpublish an action which has already been posted